# How to make md-list-item active when selected during ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

Here is my scenario

When i select any one item in list(`<md-list-item>`) an active class should be appended for the particular item.

When iam trying to do it, active class getting appended for all the items. Please help me if anyone knows the solution. Iam new to material design.

```
<md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-repeat="review in oReviews" ng-click="fnReviewEmployeeId(review.empId)">
                <img ng-src="https://x1.xingassets.com/assets/frontend_minified/img/users/nobody_m.original.jpg" class="md-avatar">
                <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
                    <h3>
                        {{review.name }}
                    </h3>
                    <span class="review-subtext">{{review.info}}</span >
                    <p class="review-status">{{review.status}}</p>
                </div>
                <md-divider></md-divider>
</md-list-item>
```

Comment: how/where you adding `active class` ? is it inside `fnReviewEmployeeId` function?

Comment: Yes it is inside that function @JAG

Comment: so that code part may be wrong.. post it in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/rLbxQj?editors=1010)

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-list>
    <md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-repeat="review in oReviews" ng-click="fnReviewEmployeeId($index)" ng-class="{selectedIndex: selectedIndex===$index}">
      <img ng-src="https://x1.xingassets.com/assets/frontend_minified/img/users/nobody_m.original.jpg" class="md-avatar">
      <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
        <h3>
          {{review.name }}
        </h3>
        <span class="review-subtext">{{review.info}}</span >
        <p class="review-status">{{review.status}}</p>
      </div>
      <md-divider></md-divider>
    </md-list-item>
  </md-list>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache', 'ngDialog'])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.selectedIndex = null;
  $scope.oReviews = [
    {name: "Cheese", info: "Dairy", status: "Delicious"},
    {name: "Beef", info: "Cow", status: "Versatile"},
    {name: "Bread", info: "Yeast", status: "Everywhere"},
  ];

  $scope.fnReviewEmployeeId = function (index) {
    if ($scope.selectedIndex === null) {
      $scope.selectedIndex = index;
    }
    else if ($scope.selectedIndex === index) {
      $scope.selectedIndex = null;
    }
    else {
      $scope.selectedIndex = index;
    }
  }
});
```

CSS

```
.selectedIndex {
  background: yellow;
}
```

Comment: This would be a good way to do it as well.  I missed that he was only selecting one item, not multiple.  My method would work better for multiple items being selected at one time

Comment: Thanks @camden_kid i missed something in if conditions in my code. This is fine for me. In my requirement i want only one item to be selected on click

Comment: @IsettyRavitejakumar - Glad to be of help.

Comment: Ooohh yes I'm about to do this with my list. I had done a similar thing with an md-switch but it hadn't occurred to me to handle the list styling like that as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can you add a boolean type property to the oReviews object? You could update that property when they click on it and then you can use ngClass to add the active class

Comment: Thanks @Dave i will check it out.

Answer (score 1):

I think Material Design handles selection differently, under List in the Docs, the example shows using a checkbox to indicate selection based on ng-model:

```
//I added the ng-click
<md-list-item ng-repeat="topping in toppings"  
        ng-click="topping.wanted = !topping.wanted">
    <p> {{ topping.name }} </p>
    <md-checkbox class="md-secondary" ng-model="topping.wanted"></md-checkbox>
</md-list-item>
```

Look for Section List Controls: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/list

Comment: That is effectively a multi-select list and is not highlighting the list item itself as a result of it being clicked. The OP is looking for a way to indicate the 'active' item in the list, which is a separate concern. Sadly, the md-list directive is missing a convenient facility for this.

Comment: Material Design seems to promote active row selection through checkboxes.  A-MD provides this directive grouping to allow single or multiple row selection. Highlighting the background color of a row may be against the spirit of their style guide: https://material.io/guidelines/components/lists-controls.html, which is reflected in my answer. I think it works well and is clean considering the styles of Material Design.

Comment: That is perfectly valid for certain applications, but I still disagree that this solves the concern raised by the OP. I have a similar issue - I have a list of reports for a user to select from. Selecting a report should highlight it and present details of the report to the right of the report list, not unlike selecting an email from a list and seeing its content in the reading pane in typical email applications. Checkboxes indicating active status for this use case are entirely inappropriate.